# looking for guidance on using and or statement to stop data being added to database

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

Hi there thanks to a member on here I managed to exclude the station name being entered if it is in the artist field now I am stuck using and or statement ..

Basically sometimes the track field also has station name in but is not limited to just the station name ....

Here is the code I have so far ...

```
if($artist != "stationname" ){

$check = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from recent where        trackartist='$artist' and tracktitle='$track' and coverurl='$cover'");
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

if($checkrows>0) {
  echo "track exists";
 } else {  

  $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO recent (trackartist, tracktitle, coverurl)
  VALUES ('$artist', '$track', '$cover')";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die('Error querying     database.');

  mysqli_close($mysqli);
 };

 }
```

What I need some guidance on is how to stop entries being made if $artist = station name & or $track contains station name in the first 7 letters of $track any guidance on this would be appreciated as have spent hours trying to research this to no avail

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a substring from $track which is the substring from the first 7 letters. After that it's pretty easy to use it in your if statement.
Here's what I suggest:

```
   $substr_tracks=substr($track,0,6)//if $track is for example 'computer' than $substr_tracks will be 'compute'.
    //now you create a boolean which will check if  'stationname' is in the substring we created.
    $bool=false;
    //now we do an if statement and use the strpos function which will check the occurence of a string or character in another string and return a number or false.

if(strpos($substr_tracks,'stationname')!=false){

    $bool=true;

} 

    //now you can do your main stuff:

if(($artist != "stationname" && !$bool) && ($artist!='stationname' || !$bool )){


//enter data into database


}else{

//do not enter into database.

}
```

**I hope I understood what you were looking for. I'm ready to answer any further questions.**

Comment: if I am understanding correctly that only checks for artist = station name & trackname contains I need it be and or

Comment: I edited the code but you can also use elseif statement to make the conditions. The parentheses  in the code sample is a simple trick.

Comment: This code gives me an error saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$bool' (T_VARIABLE)  on $bool=false;

Comment: There should be an error in your code otherwise this error has nothing to do with $bool=false. Can I see your full code please?